# HowTo add a share and chromecast button by code, not by XML in android

Tags: android, chromecast, optionmenu

I want to implement a share button and chromecast to my existing android app (API16+).
My current option menu is purely build in code.
I created a class that does all the job for onOptionItemSelected, onCreateOptionMenu and onPrepareOptionMenu.
This is because the menu is almost the same in most activities, and when the menu is build, I make a decision on logged in user, current access rights, what menues are provided to the user.
This works great so far.

Now I want to add a share button. Implementation of the share action was quick and easy with a cusom button, but how to get the right Icon ?

All samples and guides only show it by XML. The same applies for the chromecast.

I can not believe there is no way of doing the same XML does from code.

So I want to replace the XML code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

and the code

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
// Setup the menu item for connecting to cast devices
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
```

That I do not need to call the "inflate" and set up all in code.

Anyone has a hint for me ?
How do I set a menu to get a property like 
app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
from code ?

As far as I understand this will take care of all the handling and provides the icon too.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`MenuItem.html#setIcon(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon(int)) ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this allows me to set my own icon, I have to provide as a resource. But What I look for, the above code, also puts automation behind the scenes to add, hide or modify the Chromecast icon, based on the status. It also handel the required "overlay description" on first time use.

Question: Is it possible / valid to mix XML and manual created menus ? Just cam to my mind, this would help me here.